# Multiple integration with floor functions

Tags: integration

Compute the following integral

$$\int_{\Omega}(\lfloor x_1\rfloor+\lfloor x_2\rfloor+\cdots+\lfloor x_m\rfloor)dv$$

where $\Omega=\{(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_m)\big||x_1|+|x_2|+\cdots+|x_m|\leq n\}$ and $n, m\in \mathbb{N}^*$.

To better illustrate this issue, the following showcases the cases of one-dimensional, two-dimensional, and three-dimensional integrals.

In the case of one dimension, $\int_{\Omega}\lfloor x\rfloor dv=-n$, where $\Omega=\{x\big||x|\leq n\}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$.

In the case of two dimension, $\int_{\Omega}(\lfloor x_1\rfloor+\lfloor x_2\rfloor)dv=-2n^2$, where $\Omega=\{(x_1,x_2)\big||x_1|+|x_2|\leq n\}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$.

In the case of three dimension, $\int_{\Omega}(\lfloor x_1\rfloor+\lfloor x_2\rfloor+\lfloor x_3\rfloor)dv=-2n^3$, where $\Omega=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\big||x_1|+|x_2|+|x_3|\leq n\}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$.

The above three integrals are not difficult to calculate, but the most interesting thing is how to compute the multi-dimensional case. I have calculated this multi-dimensional integral using some methods, but there are certain speculative aspects involved, and I'm unsure of their correctness. Below is the result I have obtained through my calculations.

$$-\frac{2^{m-1}n^m}{(m-1)!}$$

If someone could provide a detailed procedure or correct my results, I would greatly appreciate it.

**Note**: $\lfloor x\rfloor$ represents the floor function, while $|x|$ represents the absolute value function. I apologize for not clarifying this in the question, which may have led to some misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the response from Gérard Letac, who has provided insight into the solution to this question.

By exploiting the symmetry of the integration domain, we can simplify the integral to

$$I(n,m)=m\int_{\Omega}\lfloor x_1\rfloor dv$$

Furthermore, by exploiting the symmetry of the integration domain, it can be observed that changing the sign of any variable does not affect the result. Therefore, the integral can also be expressed in the following form.

$$I(n,m)=m\int_{\Omega}\lfloor -x_1\rfloor dv=-m\int_{\Omega}\lceil x_1\rceil dv$$

By adding the two equations above, we can obtain the following result.

$$2I(n,m)=m\int_{\Omega}(\lfloor x_1\rfloor-\lceil x_1\rceil)dv=-m|\Omega|$$

So the integral value is as follows.

$$I(n,m)=-\frac{m|\Omega|}{2}$$

Thus, our objective is to calculate $|\Omega|$. We can simplify $|\Omega|$ as

$$|\Omega|=2^mn^m|\Omega'|$$

where $\Omega'=\{(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_m)\big|(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_m\leq 1),(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_m\geq0)\}$.

We introduce a new variable $x_0$ that satisfies $x_0=1-(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_m)$. At this point, we can express $|\Omega'|$ using the multivariate beta function, as shown in the following formula.

$$|\Omega'|=B(1,1,...,1)=\frac{1}{m!}$$

where $B(a_0,a_1,...,a_n)=\int_{\Omega'}x_0^{a_0-1}x_1^{a_1-1}\ldots x_m^{a_m-1}dx_1dx_2\ldots dx_m=\frac{\Gamma(a_0)\Gamma(a_1)\ldots\Gamma(a_m)}{\Gamma(a_0+a_1+\cdots+a_m)}$.

Thus, we have

$$I(n,m)=-\frac{m|\Omega|}{2}=-m2^{m-1}n^m|\Omega'|=-\frac{2^{m-1}n^m}{(m-1)!}$$.

**Note**: $\lfloor x\rfloor$ represents the floor function, $\lceil x\rceil$ represents the ceil function, and $|x|$ represents the absolute value function. The above derivation process involves the following two properties of the floor function and the ceil function.

1. $\lfloor -x\rfloor = -\lceil x\rceil$.
2. $\lceil x\rceil-\lfloor x\rfloor=\begin{cases}0,x\in\mathbb{Z}\\1,x\notin\mathbb{Z}\end{cases}$.

Answer (score 1):

Several facts: 1) you cannot get a negative result while integrating a positive function

2. If $I(n,m)$ is your integral it is interesting to make the change of variable $x_i=nu_i$ leading to $I(n,m)=n^mI(1,m)$ (and $n$ does not need to be an integer)
3. By symmetry, integrating on the $2^m$ octants of $R^m$ you get $I(1,m)=2^mJ_m$ where $$J_m=\int_{x_i>0,\ i=0,\ldots,m}(1-x_0)dx_1\ldots dx_m,$$ where we write for simplication $x_0=1-x_1-\cdots-x_m.$
4. do you know the Dirichlet integral

$$B(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_m)=\int_{x_i>0,\ i=0,\ldots,m}x_0^{a_0-1}x_1^{a_1-1}\ldots x_m^{a_m-1}dx_1\ldots dx_m$$ defined for $a_i>0\ i=0,\ldots,m?$. Its value is
$$B(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_m)=\frac{\Gamma(a_0)\Gamma(a_1)\ldots\Gamma(a_m)}{\Gamma(a_0+\cdots+a_m)}.$$

5. Using this result we have $$J_m=B(1,1,1,\ldots,1)-B(2,1,\ldots,1)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(m+1)}-\frac{1}{\Gamma(m+2)}$$$$=\frac{1}{m!}-\frac{1}{(m+1)!}=\frac{m}{(m+1)!}.$$
6. Putting things together $$I(n,m)=\frac{2^mn^m m}{(m+1)!}.$$
7. Of course integral $J_m$ is so simple that it cam be calsulated by induction without Dirichlet. But it is good to know Dirichlet, isn't?

Comment: I'm sorry, you might have mistaken the floor function for an absolute value function.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your explanation. I've already known how to derive my results.